# I inserted rows with the UTC date into an int column in my database. How can I get just the rows that were inserted in the last 24 hours?

Tags: sqlite

Here's the insert that I used:

```
db2.Insert(new QuizHistory()
{
   QuizId = quiz,
   Cards  = 0,
   Points = points,
   UtcNow = (int)Math.Truncate(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds),
   Viewed = 1,
   Deck   = deck
});
```

I tried looking at the different sql functions but now I am more confused than ever.

```
select * QuizHistory << but just for the last 24 hours.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are storing the date as seconds since january 1, 1970, a solution would be to use [`strftime`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) :

```
select * 
from QuizHistory
where UtcNow > strftime('%s', 'now', '-1 day')
```

*i.e.* with `%s` as format (seconds since 1970-01-01), for the `now` date with a -1 day modifier